# Several problems in labeling commutative diagram

Tags: equations, tikz-cd, compilation-error, tags, center

I am just trying to put some labels on the right side of some commutative diagrams in order to later reference them. Since I am not labeling all diagrams, as I only need to reference two of them, I would prefer symbols rather than numbers. Anyway, the closest I can get is by typing

```
\begin{equation}  \label{tre}
    
\begin{center}   


    \begin{tikzcd}
    
    S^n(X'') \arrow{d}{S^n(h'')} \arrow{r}{\delta^n_E}     &         S^{n+1}(X')   \arrow{d}{S^{n+1}(h')}     \\
    S^n(Y'')     \arrow{r}{\delta^n_F}  &        S^{n+1}(Y')
    
    
    \end{tikzcd}  
    
\end{center}  \tag{\bullet}


\end{equation}
```

Now, besides the fact that I get several warnings such as "Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here", this only displays the tag "(1.1)" in this left lower corner of my diagram (while I would prefer any label to be on the right and not on a lower line).
Even weirder, if I remove the "center" environment, then Overleaf doesn't compile.

I am really confused. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that we can copy and paste: documentclass and used packages as well as `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why are you using center inside an equation in the first place? Plus blank lines are not allowed in math mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a problem of commutative diagrams or anything related to `tikz`. This is just a labeling issue that can be solved with `amsmath` or `mathtools`. The later provides a command to keep the tag as in the equation. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
xyz \label{blah}\tag*{$\bullet$}
\end{equation*}
The equation~\refeq{blah} is easy
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
A\ar{r}{f}\ar{d}[swap]{g} & B\ar{d}{h}\\
C\ar{r}[swap]{k} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\label{foo}\tag*{\&}
\end{equation*}
\textit{The diagram~\ref{foo} is commutative} vs. \textit{The diagram~\refeq{foo} is commutative} 
\end{document}
```

which results in:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

First off: blank lines are not allowed inside `equation` and `center` is also disallowed. The argument to `\tag` is typeset as text, so `\bullet` will lead to an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{tre}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    S^n(X'') \arrow[d,"S^n(h'')"] \arrow[r,"\delta^n_E"] &
    S^{n+1}(X') \arrow[d,"S^{n+1}(h')"] \\
    S^n(Y'') \arrow[r,"\delta^n_F"] & S^{n+1}(Y')
  \end{tikzcd}  
\tag{\textbullet}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]